# Remove empty array in multidimensional array using laravel phpexcel

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, laravel-4, phpexcel

I want remove array if element having empty or count '0'.I used PHPEXCEL in laravel.

My Code:

```
$results=Excel::load('assets/uploads/studentdata/file.xlsx', function($reader) {

})->get()->toArray();
```

I got output is following like,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [grade] => 12 [schoolentrancedate] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2014-09-02 00:00:00 

[timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [schoolexitdate] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-06-25 00:00:00 

[timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [studentfirstname] => Gutierrez [studentmiddlename] => [studentlastname] => Larry 

[age] => [gender] => M [dateofbirth] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 1997-06-16 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] 

=> UTC ) [language] => [parentfullname] => Irma Perlera [phone] => 617-778-3913 [mobile] => 617-778-3913 [parentemail] => 

info1234@gmail.com [emergencypersonfullname] => Irma Perlera [emergencypersonphone] => 617-778-3913 [emergencypersonmobile] => 

617-778-3913 [house] => 237 [apartment] => [street] => Ferry [city] => Everett [state] => MA [zipcode] => [weekdayfrom] => 

[weekdayto] => [intime] => [outtime] => [mondayintime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 08:10:00 [timezone_type] 

=> 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [mondayouttime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 14:30:00 [timezone_type] => 3 

[timezone] => UTC ) [tuesdayintime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 08:10:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => 

UTC ) [tuesdayouttime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 14:30:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[wednesdayintime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 08:10:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[wednesdayouttime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 13:30:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[thursdayintime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 08:10:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[thursdayouttime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 14:30:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[fridayintime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 08:10:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) 

[fridayouttime] => Carbon\Carbon Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 14:30:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC ) [note] => 

[oneway] => [fromhome] => [fromschool] => [twoway] => [43] => ) 


[1] => Array ( [grade] => [schoolentrancedate] => [schoolexitdate] => [studentfirstname] => [studentmiddlename] => 

[studentlastname] => [age] => [gender] => [dateofbirth] => [language] => [parentfullname] => [phone] => [mobile] => 

[parentemail] => [emergencypersonfullname] => [emergencypersonphone] => [emergencypersonmobile] => [house] => [apartment] => 

[street] => [city] => [state] => [zipcode] => [weekdayfrom] => [weekdayto] => [intime] => [outtime] => [mondayintime] => 

[mondayouttime] => [tuesdayintime] => [tuesdayouttime] => [wednesdayintime] => [wednesdayouttime] => [thursdayintime] => 

[thursdayouttime] => [fridayintime] => [fridayouttime] => [note] => [oneway] => [fromhome] => [fromschool] => [twoway] => [43] 

=> ) 

[2] => Array ( [grade] => [schoolentrancedate] => [schoolexitdate] => [studentfirstname] => [studentmiddlename] => 

[studentlastname] => [age] => [gender] => [dateofbirth] => [language] => [parentfullname] => [phone] => [mobile] => 

[parentemail] => [emergencypersonfullname] => [emergencypersonphone] => [emergencypersonmobile] => [house] => [apartment] => 

[street] => [city] => [state] => [zipcode] => [weekdayfrom] => [weekdayto] => [intime] => [outtime] => [mondayintime] => 

[mondayouttime] => [tuesdayintime] => [tuesdayouttime] => [wednesdayintime] => [wednesdayouttime] => [thursdayintime] => 

[thursdayouttime] => [fridayintime] => [fridayouttime] => [note] => [oneway] => [fromhome] => [fromschool] => [twoway] => [43] 

=> )  )
```

I need to remove above array if array[1] ,array[2].. is empty or count '0' means its should be remove or if any other solution to avoid to read empty rows using phpexcel in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
  $data="your array";

    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
    $countstring=count(array_filter($data[$i]));
    if($countstring==0)
    {
    unset($data[$i]);  // remove empty array
    } else {
    $finaldata[] =$data[$i];  //get non empty array
    }
    }
    print_r($finaldata);
```